# Issue in Grafana Query for prometheus metric with specific labels

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql, sysdig

I have below metrics emitted from prometheus and I want to show a graph using queries.

```
demo_disk_space_state_sum{operation="remove",state="deleted"} 393.597179736
```

I am providing below query in Grafana  dashboard query filter:

```
state="deleted"
```

But there is no data shown in graph when I use this query, after removing this query, I can see the graph.

Below query works and shows the spikes in graph:

```
operation="remove"
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you please paste exact queries being used in Grafana?

Comment: @rohatgisanat demo_disk_space_state_sum{state="deleted"} i think its issue from sysdig, promql works but graphs doesnt plot.